# Baud rates applied to human communication

Tags: big-picture

The systems that I design always include large arrays of data acqusistion channels, implemented with an assortment of communication protocols, all running at different speeds. I have always wondered: Has anyone ever thought of or estimated the approximate "speed" of human speech and its comprehention? For example, 30-baud. Is the variability of human speech even quantifiable?
Thanks for considering my "goofy" question. Perhaps there might be a more appropriate forum within which to ask my question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this has indeed been considered and a keyword to find related work would be the "entropy" of natural languages. See for instance this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.06996.pdf obtained on a search engine, I am sure many more exist.

(I am also of the opinion that, unfortunately, this question is indeed not really in scope for TCS.SE.)

Comment: Thank you, a3nm, for the reference you provided and your kind pharasing concerning the appropriateness of my question within this forum. Despite it not being in scope, I appreciate you taking the time to answer. The software that I engineer acquires and processes huge amounts of data. As mentioned, I've always wondered and compared that to how we humans exchange and process auditory information. Our human systems seem so slow and complex compared to those that (ironically) we have created to process the very (large) data sets that we create. Thanks again.